# Vue D3 - Select newly generated nodes only to stop event propagation

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

Right now I'm using a custom Vue library component to generate a force graph with Pan/Zoom. The click event for the nodes are using Vue's `@click` directive, but the pan/zoom is using D3's svg `call()`, so there's a weird blend of Vue and D3 here.

The problem was clicking a node also triggered the pan/zoom function which interrupted the click event and caused nodes to be stuck in drag mode. Now, when the graph is loaded all nodes are set to stop event propagation like so:

```
mounted () {
    /* Panning currently blocks clicks, but this is bypassed by holding
       a key while clicking. */

    const svg = d3.select("svg")
    this.zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1 / 4, 4])
      .on('zoom', () => {
        d3.select('.zLayer').attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      })
    const node = d3.selectAll(".node").on("mousedown", () => {        
        d3.event.stopPropagation()
      })
    svg.call(this.zoom)
  }
```

The problem is, nodes on my graphs can be "expanded" which adds new nodes to the Vue data, which then causes the nodes to show up on the graph but WITHOUT the `d3.event.stopPropagation()`. There doesn't seem to be a unique way to call them, and trying to select all nodes and apply the `stopPropagation` on them actually removes it for all of them.

How can I get these new nodes to stop also activating pan/zoom while retaining the Vue @click functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to assign all events on **SVG** element. My solution is that we can give the svg a **rect** element as background that can trigger all zoom related events.

Here is the working code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        circles: [{cx: 45, cy: 35, r: 15}]
    },
    methods: {
        onClick: function ($event) {
            console.log($event); 
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        var svg = d3.select(this.$refs.svg);
        var layer = svg.select('.zLayer');
        var bgRect = svg.select('.bg');
        var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1 / 4, 4])
        .on("zoom", function () {
            // transform still need to work on ".zLayer"
            layer.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        });
        
        // Instead of svg I prefer rect to trigger events
        bgRect.call(zoom);
    }
});

// periodically update circles
setInterval(function () {
    app.$data.circles.push({
        cx: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
        cy: Math.floor(Math.random() * 400),
        r: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    });
}, 1500);
```

```css
svg {
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}
circle {
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke: #333;
    fill: rgba(100,150,100,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
    <svg ref="svg" width="500" height="400">
        <!-- 
        <rect> will trigger all zoom events
        Set its width and height to "100%" to make it cover the whole chart
        -->
        <rect class="bg" 
        width="100%" 
        height="100%" 
        fill="transparent"></rect>
        <g class="zLayer">
            <circle
                v-for="c in circles"
                :cx="c.cx" :cy="c.cy" :r="c.r"
                @click="onClick(c)"
            ></circle>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```